# Highlight syntax from gvim command line

Tags: vim

I have a script that generates a file and then opens it in gvim with some mappings and highlights. The highlights are defined with `au BufEnter`.

The problem is that I don't see the highlights, until I reload the file in gvim

The gvim opening command in the script is:

```
   gvim +/"${pattern}"  \
               +":hi FILE_LNnum gui=bold guifg=DarkGray" \
               +":hi f_name gui=bold guifg=SeaGreen" \
               +':nmap <Enter> <Home>vev:if match("<C-r>*","[0-9]")!=0<NL>:let @*=1<NL>endif<NL><NL><End>:call search("^FILE","bW")<NL>wgf:<C-r>*<NL>' \
               +":au BufEnter *.srch syn match FILE_LNnum \"^\(FILE\|[0-9]*:\)\"" \
               +":au BufEnter *.srch syn match f_name \"\(^FILE \)\@<=\(.*\)\"" \
               ${outputFile}
```

#### Adding a comment

I notice that the highlight command does work, and I do see it defined, but the definition of the syntax (`syn match ...`) does not work, as if it was overridden after opening the file

Comment: try using `--cmd` instead of `+` commands. Those are run before the file is loaded, so the reload should not be needed.

Comment: I tried it, and it does not help. As I added in the comment, it seems that the problem is not that it is not being ran, but that the `syn match` command is being overridden after loading the file

Comment: Then check `:verbose :set syntax?` to see when it was last set. You might need to set some kind of a variable to prevent this.